# Java Spring access based on roles/domain groups Active Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to provide access to web page only member of the group in the AD.
At the authorization stage check memberOf, eg, and user redirect to specific web page.
The application already uses method for authentification users:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
  .authorizeRequests()
---- some code ------
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
authBuilder
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .userSearchBase("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
        .groupSearchBase("OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
        .groupSearchFilter("memberOf={0}")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://regions.office.ru:389")
        .managerDn("CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
        .managerPassword("password");
```

and for searching users in the AD:

```
public class LdapSearch {
public List<String> getAllPersonNames() {
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://office.ru:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

DirContext ctx;
try {
    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
} catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
NamingEnumeration results = null;
try {
    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
    controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    results = ctx.search("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru", "(objectclass=user)", controls);

    while (results.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
        Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
        Attribute attr = attributes.get("displayName");
        String cn = attr.get().toString();
        list.add(cn);
    }
```

Which of the modules is will need for solve the problem?
I think need WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but i doubt it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help everybody.

```
public class AuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    Set<Roles> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(Roles.class);

    for (GrantedAuthority a: authorities) {
        if ("inventadmin".equals(a.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(Roles.INVENTADMIN);
        } else if ("inventuser".equals(a.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(Roles.INVENTUSER);
        }
    }
    return roles;
}
```

}

Roles:

```
public enum Roles implements GrantedAuthority {
INVENTADMIN,
INVENTUSER;

public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
}
```

}

WebSecurityconfig

```
    @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {

    authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})(|(memberOf=cn=inventadmin,OU=inventorization,OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru)(memberOf=cn=inventuser,OU=inventorization,OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru)))")
            .userSearchBase("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .groupSearchBase("OU=inventorization,OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://office.ru:389")
            .managerDn("CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .managerPassword("password");
}
```